# Initializing Data Structure

Tags: c, arrays

I have this data structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    float XYZW[4];
    float RGBA[4];
} Vertex;

    Vertex axisVertices[] =
{   
    { { -0.885f, -0.885f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, 
    { { -0.885f,  0.885f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, 
    { { 0.885f, -0.885f,  0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }
};
```

I am used to java, so this kind of things i think it is not possible with C. How can i do the following:

```
float temp1 = -0.04f;
float temp2 = -0.08f;
float temp3[] = { -0.885f,  0.885f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

Vertex axisVertices3[] =
{   
    { { temp1 , temp2 , 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, 
    { temp3, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, 
    { { 0.885f, -0.885f,  0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }
};
```

Comment: Can't you declare `Vertex axisVertices[3];` then fill it explicitly with initialization statements?

Comment: If you don't need those variables after the initialisation, try with a macro...

Comment: i dont know how to do it in C. In java we can do this, but with C i can't. I want to know if there is any way to do this.

Comment: @JohnHarrod Macmade and Basile **just suggested you two solutions.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
Vertex axisVertices3[] =
{   
    { { temp1 , temp2 , 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, 
    { {temp3[0],temp3[1],temp3[2],temp3[3]}, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, 
    { { 0.885f, -0.885f,  0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }
};
```

It is not exactly what you would like to achieve, but its near enough.